# R shiny: Produce a table from outputs of dynamically created inputs

Tags: r, shiny

How could I go about producing a subsettable `tableOutput` (`table_2`) for my `example_2`, the output of which is from a `selectInput` function created dynamically from `example_1`. Currently the tableOutput is in the form `[1] "" [1] ""`. I haven't yet been able to subset this in any way in a manner similar to my `table_1`. Thanks for your help.

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
#rm(list = ls())

ui <-  navbarPage('Example',id = "inTabset",
                  tabPanel(title = "Example_1", value = "Example_1",
                           fluidPage(
                             tags$b( h4("Example_1", align = "left")),
                             theme = shinytheme("paper"),
                             fluidRow(
                               column(6,checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label ="", 
                                                           choices = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                                                           selected = c(1,4,7)) )
                             ),
                             br()
                           ),
                           hr(),
                           verbatimTextOutput("example1")
                  ),
                  
                  tabPanel(title = "Example_2", value = "Example_2", 
                           fluidPage( 
                             tags$b( h4("Example_2", align = "left")),
                             br(),
                             fluidRow(   
                               column(4, uiOutput("VarsInput")),
                               fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("dataInfo")),
                               br(),
                               hr(),
                               verbatimTextOutput("example2"),
                                tableOutput("table_1"),
                               tableOutput("table_2")
                             ))
                  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$example1 = renderPrint(input$checkGroup)
  
  
  output$example2 <- renderPrint(
    for (i in input$checkGroup) {
      print(input[[i]])
    }
  )
  
  K <- reactive({
    length(input$checkGroup)
  })
  
  output$VarsInput <- renderUI({
    NoV = K()
    C = sapply(1:(ceiling(NoV)), function(i){paste0(input$checkGroup[i])})
    
    output = tagList()
    for(i in seq_along(1:ceiling(NoV))){
      output[[i]] = tagList()
      output[[i]] = selectInput(C[i], C[i], c("",c("a","b","c","d","e","f")))
    }
    output
    
    
    
  })


# Table 1  ---------------------------------------------------------------
  
  table_1 <- reactive({
    table_1 = input$checkGroup
    table_1 = table_1[-3]   
    table_1
  })
  
  output$table_1 = renderTable(table_1())
  

  
# Table 2 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  
    table_2 = renderPrint(
      for (i in input$checkGroup) {
        print(input[[i]])
      }
    ) # What 'input' value will allow me to produce a subsettable table?
  
  output$table_2 = renderTable(table_2())
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try another `reactive` expression as you did with Table 1. Instead of printing, you could put results into a list, and return a vector (by `unlist`).

```
  table_2 <- reactive({
    lst <- list()
    for (i in input$checkGroup) {
      lst[[i]] <- input[[i]]
    }
    unlist(lst)
  })
```

Or you could have an empty vector, and combine each result with each input value.

```
  table_2 <- reactive({
    d <- character(0)
    for (i in input$checkGroup) {
      d <- c(d, input[[i]])
    }
    d
  })
```

Note that now you can do this for your `output$example2`:

```
  output$example2 <- renderPrint(
    table_2()
  )
```

Depending on how you want to use or display the data, there are a variety of ways to further manipulate for presentation.